# Android need help with diagram

Tags: android, achartengine

i've been doing this code about making a diagram in android, but the error keep coming, am i missing something?

```
package android.research.chart;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.R;
import org.achartengine.model.SeriesSelection;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.tools.PanListener;
import org.achartengine.tools.ZoomEvent;
import org.achartengine.tools.ZoomListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class XYChart extends Activity {
  public static final String TYPE = "type";

  private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

  private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

  private XYSeries mCurrentSeries;

  private XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer;

  private String mDateFormat;

  private GraphicalView mChartView;

  private int index = 0;

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);
    mDataset = (XYMultipleSeriesDataset) savedState.getSerializable("dataset");
    mRenderer = (XYMultipleSeriesRenderer) savedState.getSerializable("renderer");
    mCurrentSeries = (XYSeries) savedState.getSerializable("current_series");
    mCurrentRenderer = (XYSeriesRenderer) savedState.getSerializable("current_renderer");
    mDateFormat = savedState.getString("date_format");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("dataset", mDataset);
    outState.putSerializable("renderer", mRenderer);
    outState.putSerializable("current_series", mCurrentSeries);
    outState.putSerializable("current_renderer", mCurrentRenderer);
    outState.putString("date_format", mDateFormat);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xy_chart);
    mX = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xValue);
    mY = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yValue);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 50, 50, 50));
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(10);

        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Kenaikan Gula Darah");
        mDataset.addSeries(series);
        mCurrentSeries = series;
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
        mCurrentRenderer = renderer;
        setSeriesEnabled(true);

        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        try {
          x = 1;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          // TODO
          return;
        }
        try {
          y = 50;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          // TODO
          return;
        }
        mCurrentSeries.add(x, y);
        if (mChartView != null) {
          mChartView.repaint();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = mChartView.toBitmap();
        try {
          File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test" + index++ + ".png");
          FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
          bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mChartView == null) {
      LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
      mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer);
      mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
      mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
      mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
          double[] xy = mChartView.toRealPoint(0);
          if (seriesSelection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(XYChartBuilder.this, "No chart element was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                XYChartBuilder.this,
                "Chart element in series index " + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex()
                    + " data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was clicked"
                    + " closest point value X=" + seriesSelection.getXValue() + ", Y=" + seriesSelection.getValue()
                    + " clicked point value X=" + (float) xy[0] + ", Y=" + (float) xy[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
      });
      mChartView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
          SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
          if (seriesSelection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(XYChartBuilder.this, "No chart element was long pressed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return false; // no chart element was long pressed, so let something
            // else handle the event
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(XYChartBuilder.this, "Chart element in series index "
                + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex() + " data point index "
                + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return true; // the element was long pressed - the event has been
            // handled
          }
        }
      });
      mChartView.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener() {
        public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent e) {
          String type = "out";
          if (e.isZoomIn()) {
            type = "in";
          }
          System.out.println("Zoom " + type + " rate " + e.getZoomRate());
        }

        public void zoomReset() {
          System.out.println("Reset");
        }
      }, true, true);
      mChartView.addPanListener(new PanListener() {
        public void panApplied() {
          System.out.println("New X range=[" + mRenderer.getXAxisMin() + ", " + mRenderer.getXAxisMax()
              + "], Y range=[" + mRenderer.getYAxisMax() + ", " + mRenderer.getYAxisMax() + "]");
        }
      });
      layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
      boolean enabled = mDataset.getSeriesCount() > 0;
      setSeriesEnabled(enabled);
    } else {
      mChartView.repaint();
    }
  }

  private void setSeriesEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mX.setEnabled(enabled);
    mY.setEnabled(enabled);
    mAdd.setEnabled(enabled);
  }
}
```

i wanted to put a value to x and y manually, and i guess i need an array for it cause i get that value from my database sqlite which has many x and y value inside.

anyone can help me to solved this problem? thanks before

edit :
i've got error in :

```
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        try {
          x = 1;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          // TODO
          return;
        }
        try {
          y = 50;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          // TODO          
          return;
        }
        mCurrentSeries.add(x, y);
        if (mChartView != null) {
          mChartView.repaint();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = mChartView.toBitmap();
        try {
          File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test" + index++ + ".png");
          FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
          bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but when i put x and y value by editText, it work, i don't know why, here's the code with editText :

```
mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        try {
          x = Double.parseDouble(mX.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          // TODO
          mX.requestFocus();
          return;
        }
        try {
          y = Double.parseDouble(mY.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          // TODO
          mY.requestFocus();
          return;
        }
        mCurrentSeries.add(x, y);
        mX.setText("");
        mY.setText("");
        mX.requestFocus();
        if (mChartView != null) {
          mChartView.repaint();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = mChartView.toBitmap();
        try {
          File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test" + index++ + ".png");
          FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
          bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
```

the problem is i don't wanna put x and y value with editText, but i want to put x and y value from database sqlite. anyone can help me? thanks before

log :

```
08-25 16:42:33.975: WARN/dalvikvm(8681): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo/org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.XYChartBuilder}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.XYChartBuilder.onCreate(XYChartBuilder.java:137)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-25 16:42:33.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8681):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: please specify what error you get and which line it's on.

Comment: the question has been edited :D

Comment: there's too much code. nobody will read through all that stuff :(

Comment: well, i've got error on the code below, the first one is the complete code, sorry about that, but i really need some help now :(

Comment: The logcat message explicitly states `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.XYChartBuilder.onCreate(XYChartBuilder.java:137)`. Have a look at the object that's being used on this line and make sure that it has been initialised correctly.

Comment: it's working, thanks, it appears that the problem occurred in bitmap line. for the next step, i want to take x and y value from database sqlite, anyone can help me? thanks before

Comment: Hi Handy, I'm running into the same issue at the moment!It works for me using the EditText but not when I give explicit values like you did. Can you please post the fix that helped you resolved this issue? It would help me and anyone else in the community who faces this in the future...Thanks in advance.