# Android AChartEngine Chart Bitmap NullPointerException

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, achartengine, linegraph

I know this question was asked earlier once but I see no answer to it from back then. Hence if you someone can guide me in this regard, I would grateful.

[Android need help with diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188556/android-need-help-with-diagram)

I have an error in the below part:

```
        double x = 0;
    double y = 0;


    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        x=x+10;
        y=y+5;
        mCurrentSeries.add(x, y);
    }

    Log.i("Series Count",""+mCurrentSeries.getItemCount());


    for (int xy=0;xy<10;xy++)
    {
    Log.i("Series -- Values","["+mCurrentSeries.getX(xy)+","+mCurrentSeries.getY(xy)+"]");
    }

    if (mChartView != null) {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = mChartView.toBitmap();

    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "test" + index++ + ".png");
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);   

        output.flush();
        output.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(LineChartTestActivity.this, "Graph Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//Added Toast to see exception on device
        Log.e("ERROR", "BITMAP EXCEPTION");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

To be specific the below line gives me a java.lang.NullPointerException

```
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
```

Like Handy mentioned in his question, I'm also able to make it work using the editText but for some odd reason it will not work when I give explicit values from the code!

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be an opened issue for this. Please see the comments [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=33), maybe it will help you get the bitmap saved.